# 'PHP artisan tinker' console command doesn't know HOMEDRIVE

Tags: laravel, tinker

this is my first time here. Surely not the last. I am working with Laravel and am trying to get into `php artisan tinker`. This is the second time I am using Laravel and tinker, after I first worked through a tutorial. Everything worked fine then. Now, when I enter `php artisan tinker` into the console, it tells me this:

ErrorException

```
Undefined index: HOMEDRIVE
at C:\[ProjectName]\vendor\psy\psysh\src\ConfigPaths.php:176
```

I tried moving back into the old tutorial project, and there it seems to work just fine. Then I tried creating a third project, but there it again does not work. So it seems that every new project has this same issue. Google doesn't help me, maybe because I'm a noob. I tried composer update, but I don't even know if that would be relevant, and it didn't do anything anyway. Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Any solution found yet?